# how to create Element with onclick and unique id with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an element with javascript which should look like below:

```html
<span onClick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, '.uniqueId()')">Select All</span>
```

I want to replace `.uniqueId()` with a unique ID generated.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
spanElement.innerHTML = 'Select All';
spanElement.uniqueId = 'your_unique_id'
spanElement.onclick = function() {
  console.log(this.uniqueId);
};

document.body.appendChild(spanElement);
```

You can also play with it here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/jrybt60n/

Answer (score 1):

Rather creating the `span` element dynamically, use a intermediate function:

```
function copyfieldWithUniqueID(event) {
    var uniqueID = uniqueID() // get a unique ID
    return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, uniqueID);
}
```

HTML:

```
<span onclick="copyfieldWithUniqueID(event)">Select All</span>
```

(Use `onclick` instead of `onClick` attribute)

And from the answer [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Define a function:

```
function uniqueID() {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                .toString(16)
                .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
            s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```